# Excel VBA Paste Special values

Tags: vba, excel

I need to edit on this below code to copy data to another workbook as value only

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Source.xls").Worksheets(2).Columns("A:E")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Target.xls").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
     Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

     Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Source.xls").Worksheets(2).Columns("A:E")
     Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Target.xls").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")

     sourceColumn.Copy
     targetColumn.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     Application.CutCopyMode = False

  End Sub
```